# Firebase maps retrieving latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this map controller where I want to get the latitude and longitude coordinates to make annotation to the map. For some reason, I don't know how to set up an asynchronous call correctly and nothing is ever retrieved from the database.

What is the best way to get my coordinates stored as doubles?

```
var restaurantArray = [Restaurant]()


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var segments: UISegmentedControl!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchRestaurants()
    print(restaurantArray.count)
    title = "Maps"
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Main Menu", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(SSASideMenu.presentLeftMenuViewController))
    self.locationManager.delegate = self//as soon as loaded find location--conforms to delegate
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest//best location
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()//only want location when using app
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()//turn on location manager..make location start looking
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true//shows blue dot

}



func fetchRestaurants(){
    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("AthensRestaurants/Restaurants").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var results = [Restaurant]()

        for res in snapshot.children{
            let res = Restaurant(snapshot: res as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            print(res.address)
            results.append(res)
        }
        self.restaurantArray = results
    })
}





//MARK: - Location Delegate Methods
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {//didupdate is contiously called so below is continuously called
    let location = locations[0]
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)//lat long--region that we want map to scope to--parameters is closeness zoom
    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)//since we have thise we can stop updating eventually
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}

//check for errors
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {//should be NSError but
    print("Errors:" + error.localizedDescription)
}
//segment changer for terrain, hybrid, and regular
@IBAction func segChange(_ sender: Any) {
    switch segments.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard
        break
    case 1:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.satellite
        break
    case 2:
        mapView.mapType = MKMapType.hybridFlyover
        break
    default:
        break
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is asynchronous and needs to have have time to load the data. i.e. code is way faster than the internet.

When fetchRestaurants() is called in viewDidLoad, Firebase goes out to retrieve the data and that data is ONLY valid when returned inside the closure. What's happening in your case is the print(restaruantArray.count) is executing way before Firebase has a chance to return the data and populate the array.

What needs to happen is, within the closure, populate the array by iterating over the snapshot, which is what you are doing, then reload your tableView after that for loop completes (again, inside the closure).

Oh, and you don't need to create the separate results array in the closure and then assign it to the restaurantArray. Just populate the restaurantArray directly.

Comment: I don't have a tableView.  Im trying to add annotations to a map.  Only has locationManager methods?

Comment: @AntonioRodriguez I was using tableView for the example. It doesn't really matter where the data is being stored in code - what matters is that you give Firebase enough time to retrieve that data before trying to work with it, and your code is trying to access an Array before it's populated.